# Presentation class vs Interface for View Filtering

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Why use a Presentation class instead of an Interface when filtering model properties for submission to View?

Comment: This question is a little vauge. What platform are you using? Rails? ASP.NET MVC? An implementation of MVP? Something else?

Comment: I think you need to expand your question and maybe provide an example...I can't really figure out what your asking. ASP.NET MVC has Controllers and Views, which work with and render model data....but I don't know of any presentation classes. In MVP, you usually have a view with an interface, which has a reference to a Presenter, which in turn has a reference to the interface of the view...

Comment: I think they're asking why use a ViewModel vs. an Interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[link text](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?AdapterPattern)I *think* you are asking the following:

> When passing a sub-set of properties
>   to a view, in order to limit the scope-of-knowledge, there are a number of
>   options.  Of those, one involves
>   copying the desired properties from
>   the model to an intermediate object (a
>   "presentation class" or a
>   "data-transfer object") and another
>   involves having the model implement an
>   interface and then passing that
>   interface to the view.
>
> Why would you use the former as
>   opposed to the latter?

My answer would be that sometimes you don't have access to the model in order to make it implement that interface.  Other times you don't want to pollute your model with unecessary interfaces, for instance you can theoretically have a different interface for every view and that starts adding up.

A hybrid alternative would be to use the adapter pattern to create a class that wraps your model, implements the interface, and delegates the interface calls to your model.

There is no option that's really better than the rest, it all depends on your situation and your "style."

Comment: dont understand the last part'adapter pattern'

Comment: http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?AdapterPattern

The adapter pattern allows you to treat a class that doesn't support an interface as if it did by "adapting" it, usually by hiding it within a wrapper that does implement the interface.